# What is an efficient way to view errors in Django?

Tags: django

I am trying to add a new middle ware into my Django application. However, my app now stalls when being visited. Eventually, after a long time, a 500 error surfaces.

Is there an error log anywhere on the server for Django? I want to see what the error was.

Comment: How are you hosting your Django application? It'll depend on your webserver. For example, the Django dev server prints to stdout

Comment: Thanks, I'm running Django on Passenger on a Dreamhost VPS.

Comment: In that case it should be in the error/access logs of Passenger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, logging will depend on how you are serving django (modwsgi, gunicorn, passenger, etc...), how  you have configured [django logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) and where the error occurs, i.e. if the error happens before/after django is handling the request.

If you have configured your mail host and logging, django can send you the error messages. If the error occurs and django isn't handling it, it will generally show in your server's logs.

Personally, I think one of the best ways to view django errors is using [raven](https://github.com/dcramer/raven) with sentry, either self hosted or on [getsentry](https://www.getsentry.com/). It even comes with a [wsgi middleware](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/django.html#wsgi-middleware) to catch errors on the wsgi layer.

Comment: +1 for mentioning wsgi middleware for sentry, as a way capturing fundamental errors

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you get a timeout error, you can look at your webserver logs but it will probably show nothing interesting, I suppose you are doing something too heavy in your new middleware that takes too long and then times out the request.

I really suggest you to re-check your middleware code (maybe you can add the code here)